# Is there is a way to use the default iOS settings screen module to build it inside an app?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I want to build app settings preferences inside my app which should look just like default settings preferences in an iPhone.

Can we display preferences inside the app using default iOS settings bundle?
Is there any default framework to do so?

How does iOS settings bundle work?

According to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html, app have two options for presenting preferences:

1) Display preferences inside the app.

2) Use a Settings bundle to manage preferences from the Settings app.

can iOS settings bundle work for first option?

Comment: Use a `UITableViewController`. Customise the cell to match your needs

Comment: Can you tell me how does iOS settings bundle work?

Comment: @Sabah You can open the iOS Settings app by using a URL. If your app uses the users Contacts information, Location services or something like that. But you can't open the iOS settings app directly in your app.

Comment: @Mannopson I was under an impression that we can use iOS settings bundle to display our app's settings by customising it as mentioned in this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Comment: Yes you can customise it, but it is in settings app, not yours. You are customising your entry in the settings app.

Comment: @paper1111 Thanks, thats all I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings bundle is used to display customised settings parameters (eg:like app endpoint) in settings screen entry respective to your app. *You wont be able to use in anyway the UI screens of settings app inside your own application.*